# Clearing a Calculation Form

Tags: cognito-forms, calculator

I'm putting together a Calculator type form - not for Users to "submit" entries but rather just to calculate various formulas.

Is the a "Clear Form" type of action I can assign to a Button - rather than just have the whole page reload?

So if I want to have several different forms embedded on one web page, can I "clear" one form but not others?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

This is not a supported feature. The idea behind Cognito Forms is that data will be entered and then submitted, so we do not offer a way to clear out a form. The only way to do this would be to refresh the form, and the page the form is embedded on.